# Spinner on click show warning "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed."

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, spinner, adapter

I'm creating an application that show schedules inside spinner when I'm select a worker. But when i'm select the worker and click the spinner, always show warning "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed." on logcat and show nothing on app.
*I'm get the schedule by consuming API

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
jsonArray = object.getAsJsonArray("schedule");

ArrayList<String> listSchedule = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++){
     String schedule = jsonArray.get(i).toString().replace("\"", "");
     listSchedule.add(schedule);
}
mOrderClassAdapter.changeSchedule(listSchedule, llOrderClass);
```

adapter.java

```
public void changeSchedule(ArrayList<String> listSchedule, LoadingLayout llOrderClass){
    scheduleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, listSchedule);
    sSchedule.setAdapter(scheduleAdapter);
};
```